# Extreme values affecting mean in regression analysis

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, mean, outliers

I am examining whether there is a difference in reaction time (RT) for 2 different conditions (A and B). Participants complete trials in both conditions.

First, I use a linear mixed model to assess the effect of condition on RT, with random effects of participant.

Q1: If there are outliers for RT for ** each participant's ** response distribution (rather than the population as a whole), then surely this will affect the regression results, as this involves predicting mean values (as I understand)?

Second, I take the difference in mean RT between conditions A and B for each participant. I then perform a linear regression to examine whether these scores are predicted by questionnaire scores.

Q2: Similarly, as I have used the mean RT for each participant, surely these could be affected by any extreme values within each participant's response distribution?

Is there any check or alternative method I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to CV.  Yes, both analyses could be affected by extreme scores. What to do about it depends on details, but here are some thoughts.

I am not usually a fan of transforming data, but here, I think taking logs of response time makes some sense.  (Assuming the outliers are on the high end). Taking logs changes additive effects to multiplicative ones and I think that makes sense for reaction times.  That is, we tend to think of "twice as long" or "half as long" rather than "3 seconds longer).

Another idea is to use some form of robust regression.

Yet another idea is to add a variable for trial number. This could work well if (as I suspect) response time goes down with trial number or the high outliers tend to be on the initial trial.

There could be other approaches, too. Those are just some ideas I had.

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer. I had a further look at my data. Plotting each participant's data as a separate boxplot shows that most outliers are slow responses (so not due to faster RTs as the task progressed). Most of these outliers are from one of the task conditions. I'm trying to think whether the fixed effect of task condition will account for this?

Comment: It certainly ought to do so. That's what fixed effects are for.

Comment: Thank you again. So, as I understand it, remaining outliers (within each participant's response distribution) that are not accounted for by fixed effects will probably be detected by cooks distance or normality violation? I then deal with these through robust regression, for example?

Comment: You can detect them however you like. With your data, it is probably find to assume they are there. And yes, you can use something like robust regression to cope with them.